# Placing an unspecified amount of command line inputs into an array in C

Tags: c, malloc, argc

I essentially want to read values from the command line as typed in by the user and place them into an array. My attempt at this so far is as follows

```
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <math.h>

#define     w   1.0


int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    int     tmp;

    double  *x, *v, *m, *k, *R;

    x = malloc((argc-1)*sizeof(double));

    printf("%lf\n", argc);

    for(tmp=0; tmp<argc-1; tmp++)
    {
        x[tmp] = argv[tmp+1];
        printf("%lf\n", x[tmp]);
    }
}
```

The print of the value of argc is equal to 0 yet the for loop will repeat three times which doesn't make sense and the values it gives are just completely wrong. Sorry i'm a bit of an amateur at this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your `main()` arguments, it should be `char *argv[]` not `char argv[]`

Comment: When you print `argc`, check the formatting string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems with your code, some already mentioned by others such as `argv` that needs to have a type of `char *[]`.

First of all, if `argc` is 1, then your `malloc` will fail because allocating memory of size 0 doesn't make sense.

Second, `printf("%lf\n", argc);` is incorrect. `argc` is `int` and you need to use `%d` to print it. The reason you see 0, which is wrong, is this.

Third, `x[tmp] = argv[tmp+1];` is incorrect too. `argv[tmp+1]` is a `char *`, which means it's a string. While `x[tmp]` is a `double`. You can't just assign a string to a double. What you need to do is to convert the string to a double, for example:

```
sscanf(argv[tmp+1], "%lf", &x[tmp]);
```

or

```
x[tmp] = strtod(argv[tmp+1]);
```

---

Hint: always compile your code with common warnings. With gcc, that would be `-Wall` command line argument. The compiler can tell you about many of these mistakes.

Comment: Brilliant my problem is solved, I originally had it in the form of sscanf but it wasn't working so I tried what is written above. Turns out i just missed the * in the main function!

Answer (score 1):

For a start the signature of main should be

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Then you are passed strings. You need to convert them to doubles `sscanf` will do this - see http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%lf\n", argc)` will cause a memory access violation, because:

1. `argc` is an integer type (4 bytes).
2. `printf("%lf...` attempts to read 8 bytes.

You must change it to `printf("%d\n", argc)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int i;

//calloc = malloc for N elemnts of given size
double* myArray = (double*)calloc(argc, sizeof(double));

//Check out arg 0!
for (i = 0; i<argc; i++)
{
    printf("arg [%d] = %s\n",i,argv[i]);
}
for (i = 1; i<argc; i++)
{
    sscanf(argv[i], "%lf", &myArray[i]);
    printf("myArray[%d] = %f\n",i, myArray[i]);
}
//avoid memory leak
free(myArray);
}
```

I see that my answer came a bit to late, anyways I just wanted to point out the arg[0] is not input.